# How inject 2 db context to .Net Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I want to be able to query 2 databases via injection in .Net Azure Functions solution, i injected one entity DbContext and worked fine, but how do i inject another context on Startup.cs? Heres my actual code:

***MyDbContext.cs***

```
namespace AzFunc.Library.MyDbContext
{

public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

***CustomContexts.cs***

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using StivaRiesgos.Library.MyDbContext;

public class FirstDbContext: MyDbContext
{
    public FirstDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class SecondDbContext: MyDbContext
{
    public SecondDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

***Startup.cs***

```
public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<FirstDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStringDbOne));

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<SecondDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStringDbTwo));

        builder.Services.AddOptions();
    }
}
```

***Myfunction.cs***

```
public class NotificationFunction
{
    private readonly FirstDbContext _context;
    private readonly SecondDbContext _secondcontext;

    public NotificationFunction(FirstDbContext _context, SecondDbContext _secondcontext)
    {
        this._context = _context;
        this._secondcontext = _secondcontext;
    }

    [FunctionName("NotificationFunction")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 8 * * *"){

        var querydbone = await _context.Users.Where(x => x.Active).ToListAsync(); // Returns count 0
        var querydbtwo = await _secondcontext.Users.Where(x => x.Active).ToListAsync(); // Returns count 0
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, ***MyDbContext.cs*** i have all mi tables and configurations of my database. I was working here and all good, the thing is now i have to duplicate this database for a new enviroment, lets call it *staging* and his connection string different. (Both databases are on *MS Sql Server*).

So with this scenario, i know i already have all the entities and configurations working on ***MyDbContext.cs***. Then, i create ***CustomContext.cs*** here i created two classes (***FirsDbContext.cs*** and ***SecondDbContext.cs***) to inherit from my base and already working ***MyDbContext.cs*** and this way i don't have to re-declare all my Entities or configurations in each context and then inject on ***MyFunction.cs*** toquery both databases *FirstDbContext.cs* or *SecondDbContext.cs* (this for the sake of simplicity, the real scenario is some functions query *FirstDbContext.cs* and other functions query *SecondDbContext.cs*

The issue is that both contexts aren't returning any info from his respective database. And i have no idea why, also kinda newbie on this kind of scenarios.

Thanks.

Comment: You have ```MyDbContext.cs``` , but you inject ```FirstDbContext``` and ```SecondDbContext``` ? Maybe you create those contexts but not showing them here ?

Comment: what is the issue youre encountering ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Question updated with details, thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

We have reproduced the same scenario and it's working fine.
Use the following below code with two databases on  `dbcontext`  file.

**Example code :-**

***Azure function code***

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp_inject_2_db_context_azure_functions_72552798
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly FirstDbContext _firstcontext;
        private readonly SecondDbContext _secondcontext;
        public Function1(  SecondDbContext secondcontext, FirstDbContext _firstcontext)
        {
            this._secondcontext = secondcontext;
            this._firstcontext = _firstcontext;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            var querydbtwo = await _secondcontext.Persons2.ToListAsync(); ; // Returns count 1
            var querydbone = await _firstcontext.Persons1.ToListAsync(); // Returns count 1
            log.LogInformation("First Db table data :- First Name :- "+ querydbone[0].FirstName.ToString()+" ,Address :- "+ querydbone[0].Address.ToString());
            log.LogInformation("Second Db table data:- First Name :- "+ querydbtwo[0].FirstName.ToString() + " ,Address : -" + querydbtwo[0].Address.ToString());
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

***Custom Context cs file***

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp_inject_2_db_context_azure_functions_72552798
{
    public class FirstDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public FirstDbContext(DbContextOptions<FirstDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Persons1> Persons1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SecondDbContext(DbContextOptions<SecondDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Persons2> Persons2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***startup file code***

```cs
using FunctionApp_inject_2_db_context_azure_functions_72552798;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]
namespace FunctionApp_inject_2_db_context_azure_functions_72552798
{
    public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<FirstDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer("Server=xxxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"));

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<SecondDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer("Server=xxxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"));

            builder.Services.AddOptions();
        }
    }
}
```

***First Database Table***

[image]

***Second Database Table***

[image]

***During debug function***

[image]

***Output*** [image]

Comment: Thanks for doing this. Also i see this scenario is both tables are on the same database. And that's not exactly what i'm trying to do here. My scenario is: Two databases with same tables, let's say it's like a production database and a staging database.

And i', trying to inherit one BaseContext with all the tables and configurations to FirstDbContext.cs and SecondDbContext.cs, and this way i don't need to rewrite the same code on both contexts. 

That's the thing, but i'm unsure if it's possible to achieve.